# Need injection token for something provided in root

Tags: angular

I have a service that is used throughout my app to do admin functions.
Normally all I have to do to use it is add it to the list of parameters of a constructor.

like so

```
constructor(private adminService: AdminService) { }
```

Which is exactly what is shown in the [angular.io documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

However I needed to use it a bit earlier on, like right after authentication and I am getting a weird error that I have no idea how to resolved based on the documentation.

The error message

```
 No suitable injection token for parameter 'adminService' of class 'LandingLayoutComponent'
```

admin.service.ts

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AdminService {}
    constructor(private httpService: ApplicationHttpClient) { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingLayoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    ApplicationHttpClient,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Update, shared module does it differently.

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: ApplicationHttpClient,
    useFactory: applicationHttpClientCreator,
    deps: [HttpClient, AuthenticationService, ProgressBarService]
  }],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious as to what your `ApplicationHttpClient` looks like. Does it use the `HttpClient` class? If so, then you probably should also include the `HttpClientModule` in your Application Module.

Comment: Good call. I see another module that has a different way of providing that thing. I will change it to work the same way.

Comment: That seemed to be it. I needed to import it the same way I did in another module.

Comment: Glad to hear it sorted.